# creating child node with usign fork() system call

Tags: c++, process, operating-system, fork

I'm trying create 5 child node with using fork() system call. I want to create 5 child node. But I got an error. How can I fix it ?

How many child process are created with this code?

My code:

```
int i;
for(i=0;i<4;i++){
int p_id = fork();
if (p_id==0){
p_id = fork();
break;
}
}
 if(p_id==0 && i%2 == 0){
  int j;
  for(j=0; j<2; j++){
  p_id = fork();
  if (p_id==0) break;
  }
  }
  sleep();
```

Comment: What kind of process tree shape do you want? Currently you're calling `fork ` a lot more than necessary.

Comment: Then you have 1 processes  at level 1, 2 processes at level 2, and you have to distribute the remaining 2 processes over level 3. Are they both children of the left child process? Right child process? One each?